# How to non programmatically add constraints to label and textview in my case study?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, xcode10

Screenshot of the example I am working with:

[image]

I searched for the answer in previous posts but was unable to find the answer. When I execute, the text fields are overlapping with one another and is clustered. I am not sure, what constraints to add, in order to have my layout as such when I execute in different devices, non programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had previously added some constraints, which I wasn't able to see. I had to clear all my constraints and reset to recommended constraints. The app was good when I ran in the simulator.